# Restrictions on type ENUM not enough?

Tags: mysql, enums

Can't find a straight answer to the following problem / question.

I created a database, and one of the fields is of type ENUM and restriction NOT NULL.

It works fine, but when I try to insert a record with a value that is not allowed for this field, the records is not rejected but inserted anyway with the field empty. That is, I think that it is an empty string (""), since I added the restriction NOT NULL.

I want the record of course rejected as a whole. How can I achieve that.

I assume sample code is not necessary since it is common knowledge.

Comment: are you using PHP or Python, or is this strictly mySQL

Answer (score 1):

If you insert an incorrect value into an ENUM column or if you force a value into an ENUM column with IGNORE, it is set to the reserved enumeration value of 0, which is displayed as an empty string in string context.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-enum.html

Try this:

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'; or STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Depending on if your table is transactional or nontransactional. This should take care of it through mySQL and cause it to abort and rollback with an integrity constraint before the method even tries to operate.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you should enable strict mode in mysql. To do this you should:

1. edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. add/edit sql-mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES
3. restart MySQL

This is solution on MySQL level. If you try inserting an empty value in an ENUM field, it should now be rejected.

Comment: SQL Modes can be set per session: SET @@session.sql_mode = ''. You do not need to restart MySQL to make the SQL Modes globally active: SET @@global.sql_mode = ''. Adding it to the option file (my.cnf) makes it permanent for later restarts.